# What is special about a 20byte (160bit) key?

Tags: security, web, key

I was emailed a reset key. It was 40 hex letters, so 20 bytes which is 160 bits. I thought to myself, why 160 bits? Maybe it's a 128 (key) + 32 bit (checksum or id or something). Maybe something else. I am sure it was done for a reason but why? (PS: The person on the other end seems to not want to say why or maybe doesn't know.  So asking elsewhere hasn't worked. I felt silly.)

I am sure script is written in PHP as the rest of the site is.

ha, ok, so it might be a SHA-1. But what would be hashed? I reset my password twice this evening, i am not sure how long apart but they were the same keys. I'll try tomorrow. Maybe its a datestamp + user id i wonder...

Comment: Because it fits in 3.3 ATM cells? Nah, I'd guess it has more to do with the size of SHA1 than anything else, but probably because it was convenient to the programmer and sufficiently hard to guess.

Comment: throw any junk into SHA1 and get something quite random **looking**: 'aardvark' ⇒ ff49abca9701606b01b6245d587d26c31b63a433; 'aardvarks' ⇒ 33ece021bcf67b6aeab8fb8ba0de55b5b92d3875; 'acidzombie24' ⇒ 973c16b5129c681551d194f59502120b73bef15c; ; 'acidzombie25' ⇒ fb24ca75c684d0e82c77801fc9e8286fcbca6791 etc.

Comment: And you may have found a security hole if you got back the same "key". As most password resets have timeouts attached, a very simple minded implementation could be using today's date and a user-id. If the author didn't know enough about "known plaintext attacks" it is quite possible that the implementation is botched.

Comment: msw: I was thinking now how it really could be anything. Then i saw your comment. I guess throwing anything in there can make a good key/pass. You really cant guess what it is. (unless you seen the code maybe). I think this question is over.

Comment: @msw: Interesting, how would that be done? I was thinking about simply doing sha1(Date("Ymd") + userId + "salt but perhaps these guys didnt do it but most likely they did"); (trying without salt this didnt get me the key the email sent). I looked at the wiki and it didnt say anything i dont know. Do you mean guess the input data and see if i can find a matching key? or is there some other way/attack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RFC 3174
http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3174.html

(aka SHA-1)

Answer (score 5):

It could be a [SHA-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1) hash, which has 160 bit.

Answer (score 4):

160 bits is the size of a SHA-1 hash.